# Memory efficient way to get sum of selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, memory-efficient

I was running a dataset of about 50m rows, and was trying to get sum by each row of selected columns, it works but after couple rounds of calculation i got memory error.

```
calcolumns = [col for col in data.columns if 'value' in col]
data['valuesum'] = data[calcolumns].sum(axis=1)
```

I was getting all column with 'value' in it's name and get sum by each row. Is there a more memory efficient way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your memory usage look like before doing the sum?

Comment: I didn't track exactly how memory was consumed but it throws memory error after couple of runs. @0x5453

Comment: Are you running this in an interactive session such as iPython/Jupyter?  I don't think that `sum` is the problem, but perhaps that your DataFrame is too large, or you have too many large DataFrames in scope at once.

Comment: Yes i was running it on Jupyter notebook @0x5453

Comment: In that case you will probably just need to be more conscious about the lifetimes of your DataFrames.  Python will not clean up old memory until that memory is no longer being referenced.  You can `del` old DataFrames that you aren't using, wrap calculations in functions, reuse old variable names (e.g. `df = df.do_something()` instead of `df2 = df1.do_something()`), etc. to make sure that references to old DataFrames don't hang around.

Comment: May be the dataset itself was too big. I kept the same dataframe name all over, and avoid forloop in any calculation, but still get memory error just after couple of simple calculations. Is there a way to force python release memory back? @0x5453